# How can I make dropdownlistfor selected value persist after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following block of code is used to make the selected value of a dropdownlistfor persist after submit:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Value, new SelectList(Model.Values, @Model.Value))
```

In this block of code, `Model.Values` is a list of strings and the `@Model.Value` specifies which value is selected.

This block of code works great but I'm trying to do the same thing with a list of `SelectListItem`s (rather than a list of strings). In the following code `Model.Values` is a list of `SelectListItem`s.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Value, Model.Values, Model.Value,
     new 
     { 
         id = "ValueDD", onchange = "this.form.submit()" 
     })
```

Is it possible to use `@Model.Value` as I did in the first code block to set the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectListItem` has a property `Selected` that needs to be set for the selected item, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.ASPX

So in your controler you can just set the `Selected` property of the item that needs to be selected, assuming you are using the controler to build the list of `Model.Values`

Comment: Yes, I tried that (and it worked), but I really like the simplicity of using `@Model.Value`.

Comment: However, I think I can see why the `@Model.Value` wouldn't work: In the first example the `List<SelectListItem>` is created in the view so I'm able to also set the `Selected` value in the view. However in the second example the `List<SelectListItem>` is created in the controller, so the `Selected` value needs to be set in the controller.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure you could iterate the `Model.Values` list in the view before creating the `DropDown` but this is going to be hacky at best